# Problema con test unitario java

Tags: java, test

```
public boolean checkNombre(String nombre){
    return nombre.length() >= 6;
}
```

Este es el metodo que quiero ver con el test unitario

```
@Test
public void checkNombre() {
    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    boolean checkNombre = user.checkNombre("oac");
    assertTrue(checkNombre);
}
```

Y este mi test unitario pero cuando lo ejecuto me dice que no se esta ejecutando ningún test unitario

Comment: ¿Cómo lo ejecutas?

Answer (score 0):

Has probado de hacerlo con un "assertEquals" en vez de un "assertTrue"?.

Si le aplicas un "assertTrue" el test está esperando una variable con un parámetro ya aplicado y en el assert le estás pasando una variable vacía, porque a pesar de que la estás igualando arriba a esa palabra, en los test unitarios, los assertTrue tienes que igualarlo a algo para que devuelva x resultado :)

Yo lo haría así:

```
@Test
public void checkNombre() {
    Usuario user = new Usuario();
    boolean checkNombre = user.checkNombre("oac");
    assertEquals(checkNombre, oac);
}
```

Saludos!